# duplicate symbol '_lprofMergeValueProfData'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xctest

I'm developing a framework "CurrentFramework" with a dependency "Dependency1", it works fine with running the example project, building the framework and testing.

but when i want to gather code coverage for the framework the following error occurs:

```
duplicate symbol '_lprofMergeValueProfData' in:
    /directory/Documents/CurrentFrameworkProject/Pods/Dependency1/Dependency1.framework/Dependency1
    /directory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CurrentFramework-hhnbyyjwzomjgjasdrewahvxlmyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CurrentFramework.framework/CurrentFramework
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried doing this with 3 other frameworks importing "Dependency1", only 1 of them can get the code coverage data without error.

Some people suggested to check if i imported a ".m" instead of a ".h" somewhere but i don't think thats the case(i checked all the files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best answer, but here's some workaround i've done.

1. Make a file to store excluded symbol (_lprofMergeValueProfData). In this example i name it hidden_list.
   [hidden_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7vBg.png)
2. Put the file on project root directory.
3. In your Xcode Project, Go to your Target and search Unexported Symbols File in Build Settings. add your file name containing list to exclude (hidden_list).
   [excluded_symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDeLB.png)
4. Run your project again, the error should be gone.